# Why aren't I converting 1,564 to binary correctly?

Tags: binary

I am trying to teach myself how to convert to binary using the subtraction method.

$$
1564-1024=540
\\
540-512=28
\\
28-16=12
\\
12-8=4
\\
4-4=0
\\
\;
\\
\to 11000001100_2
$$

But $1,564 =11000011100_2\neq11000001100_2 = 1,556$

What did I do wrong to get the incorrect result here?

Comment: $1565-1024=541$

Comment: $1565-1024 = 541$ ...

Comment: Sorry guys, that was a typo, I should've typed 1564.

Comment: Finally, since we end up with $1564=1024+512+16+8+4$, which are the $10,9,4,3,2$-th powers of $2$, we should get the binary number $11000011100_2$.

Comment: $11000001100_2=1024+512+8+4=1548$, not $1556$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1564 = 1024+512+16+8+4=11000011100_2$